# Azure Web deployment task failed - There is an unclosed literal string

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-webapps

I created a basic web MVC app in vs 2017 and tried to publish it on Azure. 
Tried to use existing app service and created a new as well, but both failed. 
Received this error - 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. ((20-Jun-19 12:40:32 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

(20-Jun-19 12:40:32 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
There is an unclosed literal string. Line 1, position 70.

```
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32 curPos, Char quoteChar, NodeData attr)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(TextReader textReader)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageDeserializer..ctor(Stream stream, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId, String user, String siteName)  WebApplicationForAzure      0
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, kindly check to see if the app works fine locally.
A deployment issue is an issue that causes the wrong set of files to get deployed to your site folder (typically site\wwwroot), or that causes some files not to get deployed at all. 
A runtime issue happens when the files in your wwwroot folder are exactly what they should be, but for some reason the site doesn't run correctly.
[Make sure site correctly deploys locally](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Make-sure-site-correctly-deploys-locally) for isolating the issue. Are you deploying to staging slots?

Set WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM=false in the Application settings from the Azure Portal, re-download the publish profile and then re-try to see if that helps.

1. Navigate to your problematic app in the Azure Portal.
2. Go to Configuration settings blade.
3. Under Application Settings, set WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM = false
   Ensure that the ‘false’ key is in the value field.
4. Reset and re-download the publish settings again in VS.

Also, isolate to see if it is due to network proxy or port on your system.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these steps. My office is blocking publishing on the network, I'll give your answer a try from my home system.